# CSS - How to only apply a style to a div that is inside another div?

Tags: css

This would be easier to explain with an example:

I have a div ID that is used many times on my page.

I would like to style only 1 of these div's differently, without changing its name.

Is there a way to style this 1 div, if it is inside another div?

For example, my page contains many of these:

```
<div id="text2">Some text</div>
```

And the one I wish to change is:

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="text2">Some different styled text</div>
</div>
```

Is this possible?

PS. This is all with Wordpress, therefore they are dynamically generated. Adding individual inline CSS with `style` will not work. This MUST be done in my external CSS sheet.

Comment: An `id` should be unique, use a class instead.

Comment: Agreed.  Only one element should match an ID per page.

Comment: WordPress doesn't generate duplicate ID's, unless multiple instances of `wp_nav_menu` display the same menu. You should modify the broken code to fix the duplicate ID.

Comment: It's the widgets that are being duplicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you could treat the inner div witin a div as a child and as a result you can use this css

```
#container #text2 {
  /* Unique Div Style */
}
```

It is correct that if you have an element that is being repeated a lot,, you should use a class and not an id.

If you have a lot of

```
<div id="text2">Some text</div>
```

then it should really be like this

```
<div class="text2">Some text</div>
```

If you do that then your CSS could look like this for that ONE div that you want to style differently

```
#container .text2 {
  /* Unique Div Style */
}
```

Of course, provided that your container ID is unique ID.

ALSO, if you changed your code and you styled repetitive elements with classes then you could apply multiple classes to the same element..

Like so:

```
<div class="text2 text2new">Some text</div>
```

Now you could write CSS for class .text2new

```
.text2new{
    /* make sure your css code overrides the old class*/
}
```

If it is important to you to have the site display correctly in older browsers multiple classes are not supported btw.

Hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: Ahhh thanks! No idea why I didn't think of this haha... Been using CSS for 5 years now and I was thinking far to complex.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
#container #text2 {
  /* YOUR CSS HERE */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As commented above, if you want to apply the same style to multiple elements, use class instead of id. Styles could be applied to specific elements following the specified structure, which means in your case, you should be using

```
#container .text2 {
  // styles go here...
}
```

If however your text2 remains an id, the style would only be applied to the first element with that particular id found.