# Is it possible to apply a custom style to a specific div instead of the whole page

Tags: css, scrollbar

I want to apply a minimalistic stye instead of the default scrollbar chrome has, is it possible to add custom styles to an element's specifically, preferably without jquery.

Comment: Does the div have a class that is different than the rest of the page? Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20231369/7948962

Comment: Scrollbars are notoriously difficult to change since they are a browser element; some browsers don't let you change them. So your answer is "yes" but not always.

Answer (score 0):

To make a really simple custom scrollbar you could do this:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {


  width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
```

Customize values if you want.